# Laravel foreach array on view

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have array like this, can you help me how to foreach to view.

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "19"
}

Comment: Your question is not completed enough to understand the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array like this:

```
$array = ["2", "19"];
```

You can view it using the blade template engine like so:

```
@foreach($array as $item)
  {{$item}}
@endforeach
```

If you just want to access it in normal PHP though it would be like:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
  echo $item;
  // or whatever you want to do with the information here
}
```

Is this what you are trying to do?